# Connect docker to docker containers using wildcard subdomains

Tags: django, docker, dns, docker-network

I can connect to other docker services from a docker container using their service names. So for example, I can do a get request to my flask app using `http://flask-container:5000` from my django app directly. I could also call one django app from another app (same container) using `http://django-container:5000/someurlpath`.

The django project is configured to use [django-hosts](https://github.com/jazzband/django-hosts) for subdomains. From my host machine it works using an nginx-proxy. Is there any docker-compose configuration way, such that I can call the subdomains using the service names such as `http://api.django-container:5000`?

Comment: Did you find a neat solution?